# Extraer letras y espacios de un string

Tags: php, regex

yo tengo un string, por ejemplo

**string= "Hola Como andan? =) "**

Yo necesito tomar ese string y llevarme solamente las letras y espacios, es decir, que me quede así:

**string= "Hola como andan"**

Yo para lo que es el numero de teléfono aplique lo siguiente:

```
    // Toma todo el string y solo deja los números y en caso de que devuelva menos de seis dígitos lo reemplaza por nada.
function telefono($numero) {
    $r = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $numero), 10);
$tam = strlen($r);
    if($tam < 6){$r = null;}
return $r;
}
```

En donde tomo solo los números del campo y me fijo que tenga por lo menos 6 dígitos para que sea valido.

¿Alguien me podría dar una mano? Muchas gracias!

EDIT:

La funcion que estoy usando es la siguiente que solo me toma las letras:

```
function limpiar($var) {
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/iu', '', $str);
return $str;
}
```

Comment: Si, es esta: Pero solo me toma letras:
function limpiar($var) {
 $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/iu', '', $str);
return $str;
}

Comment: @gbianchi Listo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
function limpiar($var) {
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ\s]+/u', '', $var));
}
```

Realmente hacemos dos reemplazos. En el primero borramos cualquier cosa que no sea letra del alfabeto español y cualquier tipo de espacios (esto incluye posibles saltos de línea)

Después, remplazamos 1 o más 'espacios' por un único espacio.

Si no necesitases la limpieza de espacios, simplemente puedes utilizar:

```
function limpiar($var) {
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ\s]+/u', '', $var);
}
```

Importante: en tu ejemplo, la función limpiar recibe el parámetro `$var`, sin embargo, luego dentro no referencias a `$var` en absoluto. Y en su lugar referencias a `$str`. Alguna de las dos cosas es incorrecta. Tienes que cambiar la definición de la función o referenciar a `$var`

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado:

```
// Toma todo el string y solo deja los numeros y en caso de que devuelva menos de seis digitos lo reemplaza por nada.
function limpiar($str) {
    return $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]/iu', '', $str);
return $str;
}
```

Al usar esta función reemplaza cualquier emoticon o simbolo extraño

Comment: Parece bastante acertado, pero tiene dos problemas: 1) Falta añadir `ü` y `Ü` como carácteres admitidos. 2) Con la siguiente entrada: `hola[salto-de-linea]como estas?` devolvería `holacomo estas` (juntaría hola + como)